# Highlight Certain Text Background In Text View With Case Insensitive

Tags: android, normalization, spannable

I want to highlight certain text background with some color with case insensitive. I tried the code below but it's not working. It only highlights when the keyword is in lowercase.

```
 private static CharSequence highlightText(String search, String originalText) {
    if (search != null && !search.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        String normalizedText = Normalizer.normalize(originalText, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "").toLowerCase().;
        int start = normalizedText.indexOf(search);
        if (start < 0) {
            return originalText;
        } else {
            Spannable highlighted = new SpannableString(originalText);
            while (start >= 0) {
                int spanStart = Math.min(start, originalText.length());
                int spanEnd = Math.min(start + search.length(), originalText.length());
                highlighted.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                start = normalizedText.indexOf(search, spanEnd);
            }
            return highlighted;
        }
    }
    return originalText;
}
```

For example I have a original text = "I Love Stackoverflow" and the keyword is "i love". How can I highlight the text background of "i love" without changing it to lower case and maintain the case.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer from here:
[Android: Coloring part of a string using TextView.setText()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext)

```
String notes = "aaa AAA xAaax abc aaA xxx";
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(notes);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("aaa", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(notes);
while (m.find()){
//String word = m.group();
//String word1 = notes.substring(m.start(), m.end());

sb.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), m.start(), m.end(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
}
editText.setText(sb);
```

Comment: this does not highlight the background as asked in the OP

Answer (score 0):

As an update [Mei Yi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46678979/7311767):

If you set a layout attribute on the `TextView` such as `android:textAllCaps="true"` it may overwrite the Spannable string used to set the highlight and look like it isn't working. That is easy to work around; just set the layout attributes programmatically.

Ex. `textView.setText(text.toUpperCase())` instead of `android:textAllCaps="true"`

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue

```
String text = "I Love StackOverflow";
String hilyt = "i love";

 //to avoid issues ahead make sure your
// to be highlighted exists in de text
if( !(text.toLowerCase().contains(hilyt.toLowerCase())) )
return;

int x = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(hilyt.toLowerCase());
int y = x + hilyt.length();

Spannable span = new SpannableString(text);        
span.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), x, y, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

yourTextView.setText(span);
```

The secret is changing all cases of both strings to lower case  while trying to get de position of our text to be highlighted.
I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here is a function to search specific query in a text message.

private fun highlightSearchText(message: String, searchText: String):SpannableString {
 val spannableString = SpannableString(message)
 val startIndex = message.indexOf(searchText, ignoreCase = true)

 if (startIndex != -1) {
     val endIndex = startIndex + searchText.length
     val span = BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW) // Highlight color
     spannableString.setSpan(span, startIndex, endIndex, 
      Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }
    return spannableString
 }

// call above function for list of messages and update adapter accordingly

private fun searchQuery(s: String) {
     messageItemList.forEach {
        it.body = highlightSearchText(it.message!!,s)
     }
        mChatListAdapter.submitList(mChatList)
        mChatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
 }
```