# How to set color on string

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to set color just on "read more" string :

```
    holder.Title.setText(current.getTitle());
    holder.Description.setText(start+"...."+"read more");
    holder.Date.setText(current.getPubDate());
```

I have tried to use html.fromhtml but it is not working with me !!!

Comment: use `holder.Description.setTextColor()` to set the color of text.

Comment: @crammeur the question asked to make red color only in a substring of holder.Description

Comment: @Lino thank to say this to me I don't see :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Coloring part of a string using TextView.setText()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext)

Comment: may be helps you https://github.com/milaptank/SpannableTextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as follow

```
String textFirstPart = start + "....";
String textSecondPart = "read more";
String text = textFirstPart + textSecondPart;
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text);
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), textFirstPart.length(),
                            (textFirstPart + textSecondPart).length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
holder.Description.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from **Android N**,

the method **Html.fromHtml(htmlText)** is deprecated and you have to use

**Html.fromHtml(htmlText, MODE)** instead, so use the following condition,

```java
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
           holder.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
           holder.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString);
        }
```

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
 SpannableString styledString = new SpannableString("read more");
 // change text color
 styledString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 8, 0);
 // underline text
 styledString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, 8, 0);
```

Read more [here](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.com/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html)