# How do I use EditableFactory in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, spannable

My EditorFactory is crashing under Google Play testing. The class is embedded in a Renderer I have wrote to extend the Xamarin Forms Editor control.

```
Error:

    FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
Process: com.MyApp.MyApp, PID: 23307
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at MyApp.EditorExRenderer+NoCopyEditableFactory.NewEditable (Java.Lang.ICharSequence source) [0x00000] in <0c33163fb4704d40bbc13286b4698089>:0 
  at Android.Text.EditableFactory.n_NewEditable_Ljava_lang_CharSequence_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_source) [0x0000f] in <0ce592b1e5104b27bf696797bee3407f>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_L (_JniMarshal_PPL_L callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0) [0x00005] in <0ce592b1e5104b27bf696797bee3407f>:0 
        at crc645beb7f91af2d2a49.EditorExRenderer_NoCopyEditableFactory.n_newEditable(Native Method)
        at crc645beb7f91af2d2a49.EditorExRenderer_NoCopyEditableFactory.newEditable(EditorExRenderer_NoCopyEditableFactory.java:29)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6219)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6156)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:121)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6108)
        at androidx.test.espresso.action.ReplaceTextAction.perform(ReplaceTextAction.java:1)
        at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridInteractionController$1.perform(HybridInteractionController.java:2)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:2)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:21)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.-$$Nest$mdoPerform(Unknown Source:0)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:6)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

A skeleton of my renderer code is below. I hope it's enough to give a rough idea of how I'm using the factory:

```
public class EditorExRenderer : EditorEx
{
  public EditorExRenderer(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context)
  {
  }

  private class NoCopyEditableFactory : EditableFactory // Editable.Factory in Java
  {
    public override IEditable NewEditable(ICharSequence source) => (IEditable)source;
  }

  void Load(string displayString)
  {
    ...
    ...
    SetSpannable(displayString);
    ...
    ...
  }

  void SetSpannable(string text)
  {
    _spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

    //set span
    Span span = new Span();
    ...
    ...
    _spannable.SetSpan(span, start, end, SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
    ...
    ...

    Control.SetText(_spannable, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);

  }

  private void Control_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    ...
    ...

    SetSpannable(newText);
  }

}
```

Any ideas of why it might be crashing?

Comment: Looks like exception is telling you that `public override IEditable NewEditable(ICharSequence source) => (IEditable)source;` is an `invalid cast`. Add debugging code or breakpoint to find out the class of `source`. It seems that it isn't a class that inherits from `IEditable`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Steve, I have a solution, will post here.

Answer (score 1):

`ICharSequence` and `IEditable` are two different kinds of interface. So we can't do a type cast between them.

In addition, you can try to create a instance of the EditableFactory and use it somewhere. Such as:

```
var NoCopyEditableFactory = new EditableFactory();
Control.SetEditableFactory(NoCopyEditableFactory);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Liyun, I've worked it out and will post soon. With regards to the constructor, the **Control** will be null until the `protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)` method is called. That's why I delay its usage.

Comment: No worries, aside from that your solution is fine and was helpful. For the benefit of other readers I think both solutions can be accepted as answers. I can't vote for my own answer, so I'll vote for yours. Feel free to vote for mine as well if you think it is also an acceptable solution. Cheers

Comment: After further testing, I discovered my new solution doesn't work. Please see an **Update** to my "Answer" above.

Comment: Do you mean this line `textPaint.Color = Color` doesn't work? @jho

Comment: In the `SpanChange()` method, when I call `span.SetColor()` followed by `Invalidate()`, I believe the colour should change automatically. It doesn't so I re-Set the span to `_spannable`, and it worked. Now with my new code, even that doesn't work.

Comment: I can't find the setColor method of the span. It just has the BackgroundColor, ForegroundColor and TextColor property.@jho

Comment: You can try to create the instance of the span by the construction method, such as `Span span = new ForegroundColorSpanEx(cb.Color)`.@jho

Comment: Please see my derived class in the code below: `public class ForegroundColorSpanEx : ForegroundColorSpan`. I corrected the code too to reflect it was a `ForegroundColorSpanEx`, not just a `Span`. My bad.

Comment: Just set the correct `ForegroundColorSpanEx`, and same problem. In actual fact the error wasn't in my base code, it was in the code I edited for posting here at stackoverflow. The other odd thing is when I put a breakpoint on `UpdateDrawState`, it correctly reflects the change in color, but the new color is not updated on screen.

Comment: But according to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext), everything is right.@jho

Comment: Actually, I can't understand what you want clearly. Do you want to change the editor's text color in the xamarin.forms?@jho

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246456/discussion-between-jho-and-liyun-zhang-msft).

Answer (score 1):

I had copied the **NoCopyEditableFactory** blindly from another StackOverflow post, so I removed it and everything works fine:

```
public class EditorExRenderer : EditorEx
{
  public EditorExRenderer(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context)
  {
  }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            ...
            ... 
            //****************
            //create new SpannableFactory, rather than NoCopyEditableFactory
            Control.SetSpannableFactory(new SpannableFactory());
            ...
            ... 

        }

    }

  //private class NoCopyEditableFactory : EditableFactory // Editable.Factory in Java
  //{
    //public override IEditable NewEditable(ICharSequence source) => (IEditable)source;
  //}

  void Load(string displayString)
  {
    ...
    ...
    SetSpannable(displayString);
    ...
    ...
  }

  void SetSpannable(string text)
  {
    _spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

    //set span
    ForegroundColorSpanEx span = new Span();
    ...
    ...
    _spannable.SetSpan(span, start, end, SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
    ...
    ...

    Control.SetText(_spannable, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);

  }

  private void Control_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    ...
    ...

    SetSpannable(newText);
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I discovered my new code is creating errors. With the previous **NoCopyEditableFactory**, the following **SpanChange** method could dynamically change the color of the text font. With my new code above the dynamic coloring doesn't work. I tried using the default **EditableFactory**, instead of the **NoCopyEditableFactory**, and this also doesn't dynamically color the text.

So I am back to square one again. Any ideas?

```
void SpanChange(int index)
{
  Span span;
  int start, end;

  span = _spans[index];
  start = _spannable.GetSpanStart(span);
  end = _spannable.GetSpanEnd(span);

  span.SetColor(cb.Color);

  _spannable.SetSpan(span, start, end, SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);

  Invalidate();

}


public class ForegroundColorSpanEx : ForegroundColorSpan
{
  private Color Color;

    public ForegroundColorSpanEx(Color c)
      : base(c)
  {
    Color = c;
  }
  public override void UpdateDrawState(TextPaint textPaint)
  {
    base.UpdateDrawState(textPaint);
    textPaint.Color = Color;

  }
  public void SetColor(Color c)
  {
    Color = c;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are just using the default spannable factory class, I don't think you need that line at all. TextView should already have what it needs. As a test, comment it out. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: I commented it out and you are right, it still works. Haven't run it through the more rigorous Google Play testing yet, but I suspect it will be ok there too. Cheers

Comment: After further testing, I discovered my new solution doesn't work. Please see an **Update** to my "Answer" above.

Comment: Please see my **UPDATE** section above. It explains what I regard as not working. Briefly here, yes, it is color related.

Comment: I've re edited and clarified above. Though the code no longer crashes in Google Play closed testing, the dynamic colouring no longer works.