# how to change the color of specfic word in list?

Tags: android

i have have a text file and in file, text is arranged line by line like...

The Apple is sweet.

the color of car is red.

the sky is blue..
i am serching word in file like car or apple
i am reading and searching in file using following code
{

private void initializeData() {

```
    listenglish = populateFromFile("eng_translation.txt");


@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
private List<String> populateFromFile(String fName) {

     // ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                fName), "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        if (reader != null) {
            String line;
            while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                //lstTemp.add(line);
                if (line.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())){
                    listenglish.add(line);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            line = null;
            System.gc();
            buffreader.close();
            reader.close();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }
    return listenglish;

}
```

}

now i want that the word which i search in file disply with differnt color in list how i do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change text color of one word in a TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221930/change-text-color-of-one-word-in-a-textview)

Comment: @BobMalooga it take two strings and then changing the color of second string and here i am handle a text line and in line only change the color of one word in that line i think its not same....

Comment: Well, it actually is the same: you want to search for a string in another one. If you find it, you want to change that word's color (like replacing yourWord with "<font color = ...>" + yourWord + "</font>"), And then just use HTML.fromHTML to set the text in your TextView, Right?

Comment: @BobMalooga may be you say right but i dont understand how exactaly i do it....

Comment: See the accepted answer in the link I provided. Easy. Or follow the Spannable alternative (not as intuitive, I think).

Comment: i see but the problem is that they all uses textview and here i am using list view i also use one from this but its not working may be i am using listview that why...

Comment: Well, a ListView item can contain a TextView, among the other things... just find a tutorial on how to make a customized ListView

Comment: @BobMalooga well i try and Bundle of thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this on plain String object. This must be handled in Adapter's getView. Method for doing such a thing might look like:

```
    public void setColorForWordInTextView(int color, String word, TextView tv) {
        String str = tv.getText().toString();
        Spannable span = new SpannableString(tv.getText());

        span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), str.indexOf(word), str.indexOf(word) + word.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        tv.setText(span);
    }
```

And then you can use it with:

```
setColorForWordInTextView(Color.RED, word, tv);
```

Comment: i am not usng text view i am display in listView so how can do this in listview