# Optimal way of animating color of each letter

Tags: android, performance, android-animation

Have an app with few dragable custom font `TextView`'s.

Have created a class `TextAnimator` which initiates single `ValueAnimator` and allows to add wanted TextViews which are set as `setText(textValue, BufferType.SPANNABLE);`.

By adding a new `TextView` to this `TextAnimator`, it stores a `TextView`, arrays of initial/end random colors and `Spannable` variables for each letter in `ArrayLists` of simple arrays.

On `UpdateListener` of `ValueAnimator` I iterate through all added `TextViews`, calculate color transition values and change color of each letter like this (according to suggestion here: [Change text color of one word in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221930/change-text-color-of-one-word-in-a-textview)):

```
listOfSpannables.get(indexLocation).setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.HSVToColor(listOfHSVs.get(indexLocation)[i])), i, i+1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

This animation makes my app work (dragging, other animations) very sluggish and Im not sure what is causing it. My guess is that maybe using of spannables is inappropriate (maybe I should somehow clear all added spannables before re-adding them on each iteration - how to clear them all at once?).

I could also use HTML to set color of each letter, if that would be faster. Or maybe whole approach is wrong.

Any suggestions, tips on how to improve performance?

Comment: calling `new ForegroundColorSpan` inside `AnimatorUpdateListener` which is called multiple times per second makes it sluggish, try creating a custom span similar to `FCS` where you can change the color

Comment: Not sure what does FCS stands for. Would it be better if I had single global instance of ForeGroundColorSpan and update / use it on each iteration? Or what do you mean by creating a custom span?

Comment: FCS = ForegroundColorSpan, see its sources and create your own custom wersion of FCS where you can change the color

Comment: Now I see that you cant just assign new color to the instance of FCS and need to create it anew anyway. I tried to CTRL click the name of this class, but the code shown is only half a screen and nothing to look at. How do I get the full code? And also would `setSpan()` accept a custom span object?

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/ select "android source" from the left and type `ForegroundColorSpan` in "Definition" field

Comment: Code in this website is the same as shown when CTRL clicking the name of the class and I am to big of a noob to craft something useful from what I see. I guess I'll have to try HTML formatting way to see if it gets any faster.