# Android, applying different colors to a text string

Tags: java, android

Edit... I'm going to try explain this better.

At the moment Im working with

canvas.drawtext(text, x, you, paint)

I want to align these strings if I can next to each other so they make a sentence, or have a string with  say "Iike cheese" and print it on canvas.

I'm struggling to find the solution.

Html doesn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=p9LlEvvC0t

Comment: @Aaron what do you mean by a container exactly?

Comment: @ScottChambers I missed the "Android" in the title, I added in the tags to give your question more visibility to people able to answer it. I don't think my previous comments apply to android development.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7221990/1678362) if you haven't already.

Comment: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.text.SpannableString You are looking for this.

Comment: I did say in my question that Spannable string didn't work.

Comment: @sarthak Gandhi and how do I call that SpannableString in a canvas.drawtext?