# Change a word color in String,xml

Tags: android

I have a created a `string` in my `string.xml` file and would like to change the `color` of the words Excitement, Adventurous in the sentence to `yellow`. I have tried to add `<font color="yellow">Excitement, Adventourous</font>` but this does nothing.

#### string.xml

```
 <string name="screen114_3">EMOTION Driver5- UNCERTAINTY/VARIETY (Surprise, Diversity, Challenge,<font color="yellow">Excitement, Adventurous</font>, Wild)
</string>
```

Comment: I'm unsure about this, but I think you have to use `Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.screen114_3))` here

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221930/change-text-color-of-one-word-in-a-textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CDATA` , Try this

```
<string name="screen114_3"><![CDATA[EMOTION Driver5- UNCERTAINTY/VARIETY (Surprise, Diversity, Challenge,<font color="yellow">Excitement, Adventurous</font>, Wild]]></string>
```

then add

```
String colouredString = getResources().getString(R.string.screen114_3);
    textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(colouredString));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
String text = "EMOTION Driver5- UNCERTAINTY/VARIETY (Surprise, Diversity, Challenge,<font color="yellow">Excitement, Adventurous</font>"
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```