# Android - is there a way to edit color in a part of a string that is displayed?

Tags: android

I have a part of the code that calls a toString on an object and the toString basically spits out the string that will be shown on the screen.

I would like to change the color of one part of the string.

I just tried something like this:

```
        String coloredString =  solutionTopicName + " (" + commentCount +  ")";
        Spannable sb = new SpannableString( coloredString );
        ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(140, 145, 160));
        sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), solutionTopicName.length(), solutionTopicName.length()+3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return sb.toString();
```

But I am still seeing the same colors appear without change.

Thanks!

Comment: Refer the previous posts 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032676/how-can-i-change-color-part-of-a-textview
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext

Comment: **Do not call `toString()`**. Pass the `Spannable` into whatever needs the formatted value (e.g., `setText()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it is possible

use [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) to do that.

`setSpan()` will do the job.

```
Spannable mString = new SpannableString("multi color string ");        

mString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 5, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Update:

```
String coloredString = " (" + solutionTopicName + commentCount +  ")";
        Spannable sb = new SpannableString( coloredString );
        ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(140, 145, 160));
        sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), solutionTopicName.length(), solutionTopicName.length()+3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        //textView.setText(sb);
    return sb;
```

Latest:

```
 String solutionTopicName= "Hello";
 String commentCount= "hi how are you";
 String coloredString =  solutionTopicName+"(" + commentCount +  ")";
 Spannable sb = new SpannableString( coloredString );
 sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), coloredString.indexOf("("), coloredString.indexOf(")")+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  mTextView.setText(sb);
```

Comment: I just updated my question. Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do there? I seem to have implemented much of the code, but can't get the colors to change.  Thanks!!

Comment: Trying out your new solution now :) Thanks! Lets hope it works :)

Comment: That didn't quite work. This is how the first line should be: solutionTopicName + " (" + commentCount +  ")"; ...but the issue is that the color didn't change.

Comment: Btw, what color is that supposed to end up being? :)

Comment: I just updated the question with my latest code...still no color change :(

Comment: see my latest and its working(tested) dont use `(Color.rgb(140, 145, 160));` use (Color.BLUE);

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. Do you think the sb.toString() that I am using could be messing things up?

Comment: public spannable funcName
{
..
..
return sb;
} change your function return type.(as you are converting it in normal string).

Answer (score 1):

```
I would like to change the color of one part of the string. Is that at all possible?
```

yes, you can change color of specific part of string. There is a `SpannableStringBuilder` class you can make use of it.

you can do some thing like this.

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("This is your String");
ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(140, 145, 160));
sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, 10, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(sb);
```

here is the definition of setspan method.

```
setSpan(Object what, int start, int end, int flags)
Mark the specified range of text with the specified object.
```

`setSpan` method takes indices as parameter and an instance of `Object` Class. so any class' instance could be passed in as parameter depending upon your requirement. we used instance of `ForegroundColorSpan` to change color of text. you can pass `Clickable` instance to make certain part of string clickable.

Comment: thanks, didn't have much luck. I updated my original answer to show you what I did. Maybe you can spot something I did incorrectly?

Comment: your code seems fine, i tried with your string its working at my end. dont know whats there in solutionTopicName. remember the string with changed color is only found in sb not in solutionTopicName + sb.

Comment: hmmm, not even if I concatinate like this: solutionTopicName + sb ?