# Android - How I can set color for Diacritic Arabic language?

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-typeface, android-color

How I can set color for Diacritic Arabic language ?

For example :

[image]

What can I do ? I should use `StringBuilder` or manipulate `*.sqlite` or`WebView` ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html). check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032676/how-can-i-change-color-part-of-a-textview) it may help.

Comment: I test this way erst and don't work.Show me characters separated.Thanks