# How to change text color of the part of the TextView?

Tags: android

I have simple textView controler on my application.
On this textView i set the text "123456789" - the text color is black.

I want that the three last digit ( 789 ) will be shown with red text color.

Is there any simple way to do it without using two textView controls
(one will contain "123456" in black and second will contain "789" in red )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the color of a part of a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032676/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-part-of-a-textview)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try This:

Set `TextView` as a `HTML` using `SpannableTextView`

```
String text = "<font color='black'>123456</font><font color='red'>789</font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Html.fromHtml(text) is deprecated, and Html.fromHtml(String, int) is available from api level 24..

Comment: This is not reliable and does not work on all SDK level specially on older version such as 21.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this method

```
public static final Spannable getColoredString(Context context, CharSequence text, int color) {
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text);
        spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, spannable.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return spannable;
    }
```

then later you call is by using

```
textview.append(getColoredString(this, "Hi!", ContextCompact.getColor(this, R.color.red)));
textview.append(getColoredString(this, "User", ContextCompact.getColor(this, R.color.green)));
```

Comment: This is the most reliable approach as it works across SDK level even in lower/older version.

Comment: Best answer ever for coloring the part text.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(stringB + "<font color=red>" + stringA + "</font>);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use **SpannableString** is an excellent way to style strings in a `TextView`.

[Demo](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html)

[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use HTML banners in your java class:
Example:

```
 textElement.setText(Html.fromHtml("123456 <fontcolor='#FF0000'>789</font>"));
```

Or use CData format in your XML file:
Example:

```
<string name="numbers"><![CDATA[123456<fontcolor="#FF0000">789</font>]]></string>
```

I hope that helped you ;)

Comment: I know SO is the race of posting an answer..but be careful before submitting the answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone now and I can't manage to make it show the HTML script it just desapears :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.stringname) + "" + " *" + "", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));