# android studio change color that I want in array

Tags: java, android, android-studio

There are 2 array namely `b1[],b2[]`

```java
public void compare(){
        a1=recyText.toString().replaceAll("\\s", "");
        a2=edit3.toString().replaceAll("\\s","");
        b1 = a1.split("");
        b2= a2.split("");
        for (int i = 0; i < b1.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<b2.length;j++){
                if(b1[i].equals(b2[j])){
                    edit4.setText(edit4.getText()+b1[i]);

                }
            }
         }
       }
```

I want to compare like`b1[0]=b2[0`],`b1[1]=b2[1]`  and

`if b1[i]=b2[j]` ,

I want to change `b[i]` color to Red. 
I searched setspan but it works when start in int, end is int.
How can i change the color that i want in array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032676/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-part-of-a-textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change like this it will change the background color

```
if(b1[i].equals(b2[j])){
                edit4.setText(edit4.getText()+b1[i]);
                edit4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
```

If u want to change font Color add this

```
if(b1[i].equals(b2[j])){
                edit4.setText(edit4.getText()+b1[i]);
                edit4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
else {
                edit4.setText(edit4.getText()+b1[i]);
                edit4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
```

Comment: Hi:) thank you again. I deleted public void compare {} And I add a1= ..... edit4.setText(edit4.getText()+b1[i]); into new SpeechService.Listener() {...public void run() {  if (isFinal) { ... (here)  ----> edit4 shows me Red any letters... Did I put the wrong place.?

Comment: Hi, I didn't get u. Can u update it in a question please

Comment: sorry, ummm.... if a1= Mynameiszoe      and   a2=MynameisLia   ----> i want to make Mynameis(Red color)Lia(Black color) in edit 4   . But i tried that you gave me, it changed all color red. How can i fix?

Comment: I tried, but my application isn't responding... recyText is Textview, and edit3 is Editview . I am wondering if I can compare text view and adit view like that.

Comment: yeah u can compare it. Becaues you just compare text from both editText and textView. But can u share error u got ?

Comment: I had  error(E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module). And I found how to fix it. And It worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Lia Nice to hear it. Happy coding