# Is there any way to change color of sub-string programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, substring, textview, spannablestring, android-color

I have a string resource

```
<string name="redesign_password_pattern">Your password must contain the following:\n\t&#8226; A minimum of 8 characters\n\t&#8226; At least 1 capital letter\n\t&#8226; At least 1 small letter\n\t&#8226; At least 1 number\n\t&#8226; At least 1 of the following special characters: !, @, #, $, *</string>
```

When i set this string to a `TextView`, it looks like this [image]

If the password entered by user contains a number, i want to change color of ***"At least 1 number"*** from the text and so on.

can it be achieved this way or do i need to follow another way?

So far, i tried the following way, but i don't know how to write start and end values for the string resource.

```
SpannableString spannableString =  new SpannableString(getString(R.string.redesign_password_pattern));
spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(GREEN), 101, 130, 0);
pswFormat.setText(spannableString);
```

And i don't want to write 6 different `TextViews`. Please help me to find a way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032676/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-part-of-a-textview) can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, you are only missing the start and end and the color:

```
spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 130, 147, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<string name="hello_world_test">Your password must contain the following:\n\t&#8226;
  <font color= "#F44336" name="1">A minimum of 8 characters\n\t&#8226;</font>
  <font color= "#008577" name="2">At least 1 capital letter\n\t&#8226; </font>
  <font color= "#CDDC39" name="3">At least 1 small letter\n\t&#8226;</font>
  <font color= "#008577" name="4">At least 1 number\n\t&#8226;</font>
  <font color="#9C27B0"  name="5">At least 1 of the following special characters: !, @, #, $, *</font></string>

tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world_test)));
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to change the color of sub-string programmatically.

Comment: then put the string resource on local string variable and call it like 
 tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(source);

Comment: Please understand the problem first.

Comment: @Praveen  Check my updated code. I think now you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is another way.
Format the String with html's font-color property then pass it to the method Html.fromHtml(text)

```
 String text = "<font color=#cc0029>A minimum of 8 characters</font> <font color=#ffcc00>At least 1 capital letter</font>";
 yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: I wanted to change the color programmatically.