# How to color text of RecyclerView item depending on a variable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

lets say I have a variable
isBlue = true.
If it is true I want to set my newly added RecyclerView item text to blue.
If it is false I want to set my newly added RecyclerView item text to green.

```
if(isBlue){
                dateTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.redColor))
            }else{
                dateTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.greenColor))
            }
}
```

I have tried adding this code to onBind(), but it paints all the text to the set color, repainting the previous RecyclerView item texts, so I end up with all RecyclerView item text being either blue or green.

```
private inner class SubjectDateHolder(view:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener{

        private lateinit var date : Date

        private val dateTextView :TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_subject_date)

        fun bind(date : Date){
            this.date = date

            dateTextView.text = SimpleDateFormat("d.MMMM  ''y. EEEE").format(this.date)

        }

    }

    private inner class SubjectDateAdapter(var dates : List<Date>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectDateHolder>(){
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SubjectDateHolder {
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_date, parent, false)
            return SubjectDateHolder(view)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return dates.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SubjectDateHolder, position: Int) {
            val date = dates[position]

            holder.bind(date)
        }

    }
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_subject_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"

        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: Can you provide the whole layout? (R.layout.list_item_date)

Comment: When you write code in onBind() it reflects on each item in recyclerview whether there is a conditional code or not

Comment: @FuriousSpider
Updated the with the layout file. Its a simple list item xml that I am using in my RecyclerView.

Comment: I think you could set the text color just below setting the text in your bind(date: Date) function. Just pass another argument that defines the text color.

Comment: @FuriousSpider it works if I needed to have all text the same color. But I need to color my text according to a outside variable. So some text should be blue color, some green. If I put a conditional if(isBlue){
                dateTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.redColor))
            }else{
                dateTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.greenColor))
            }
}
 I need to set the text to the color, and make it stay that color. If you get what I mean. Some text in single RecyclerView item should be blue some green

Comment: @Jaki If you set color to textView you will always color the whole text inside. If you want to color only a part of the text you can use for example Spannable. Just like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032676/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-part-of-a-textview
Hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: @FuriousSpider sorry I think you missunderstood me, sry for poor explanation.
I want my RecyclerView items to be colored differently according to my Boolean variable isBlue. If isBlue= true, and i press add, RecyclerView should add a item1 with blue text. For the next item if isBlue = false RecyclerView should add a item2 with green text. And I should end up with one item being blue and other being green. My problem is, if I add that conditional in onBind(date : Date), all off my previous items in RecyclerView have its text painted the same color.

Comment: I have posted my answer please check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61279348/12386821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly from the commentary, you want to add items to your recyclerview and want to color the new item. To do that, instead of passing a `listOf<Date>` to your recyclerview you need to pass a `listOf<MyItem>` `data class` with something like this:

```kotlin
data class MyItem(val isBlue: Boolean, val date: Date)
```

In doing so when you're in the `holder.bind()` method you can use your condition to color the text

Answer (score 0):

So you should be add one boolean key in your `API` according to color `isBlue` or `isGreen` so when you get Json you can write conditional code for color of text like..

```
if(<Your Boolean Key of Json>){
                dateTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.redColor))
            }else{
                dateTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.greenColor))
            }
}
```