# SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Tags: android

Can someone explain this error?

`"SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length"`.

I think it concerns with `editText`. Is there a solution for it?

This is my log.

```
1-07 14:29:47.654: D/OpenGLRenderer(24479): Enabling debug mode 0

01-07 14:30:36.954: E/SensorManager(24479): thread start

01-07 14:30:36.959: D/SensorManager(24479): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= 
android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@43000e98

01-07 14:30:37.139: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24479): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

01-07 14:30:37.139: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24479): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

01-07 14:30:37.419: I/Process(24479): Sending signal. PID: 24479 SIG: 9
01-07 14:30:37.654: E/Trace(25014): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

01-07 14:30:37.754: D/dalvikvm(25014): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 108K, 6% free 12258K/12931K, paused 15ms, total 16ms

01-07 14:30:37.754: I/dalvikvm-heap(25014): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.860MB for 2457616-byte allocation

01-07 14:30:37.779: D/dalvikvm(25014): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6K, 5% free 14651K/15367K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 23ms

01-07 14:30:37.809: D/dalvikvm(25014): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 14651K/15367K, paused 11ms, total 11ms

01-07 14:30:37.819: I/dalvikvm-heap(25014): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.018MB for 4367376-byte allocation

01-07 14:30:37.834: D/dalvikvm(25014): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 18917K/19655K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 16ms

01-07 14:30:37.834: D/dalvikvm(25014): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms

01-07 14:30:37.894: D/dalvikvm(25014): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2660K, 17% free 17674K/21063K, paused 13ms, total 13ms

01-07 14:30:37.909: D/dalvikvm(25014): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 688K, 14% free 18212K/21063K, paused 10ms, total 10ms

01-07 14:30:37.944: D/dalvikvm(25014): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 18890K/21063K, paused 12ms, total 12ms

01-07 14:30:37.949: I/dalvikvm-heap(25014): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.170MB for 1235556-byte allocation

01-07 14:30:37.964: D/dalvikvm(25014): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 20097K/22279K, paused 11ms, total 11ms

01-07 14:30:38.019: D/libEGL(25014): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so

01-07 14:30:38.024: D/libEGL(25014): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so

01-07 14:30:38.024: D/libEGL(25014): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so

01-07 14:30:38.029: D/(25014): Device driver API match

01-07 14:30:38.029: D/(25014): Device driver API version: 10

01-07 14:30:38.029: D/(25014): User space API version: 10

01-07 14:30:38.029: D/(25014): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Fri Sep 28 

10:42:56 KST 2012 

01-07 14:30:38.064: D/OpenGLRenderer(25014): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: show your logcat
not enough info to pin on to error

Comment: i post the log please take a look

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879233/explain-the-meaning-of-span-flags-like-span-exclusive-exclusive
take a look this post

Comment: i post the complete log Usman

Comment: please post the Xml of EDITTEXT

Comment: <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eddDuree"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lbl_duree"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lbl_duree"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbl_duree"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox"
                android:clickable="false"

Comment: android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="@dimen/content_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

Comment: sorry for the presentation but having problem to post this with stack overflow. this is my edittext from my xml.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. See [here][1] for a (partial) solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just add this property to your edit text and your problem will definitely be resolved

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Add the above property to each of your edit text used in the application, or simply where you get the error in that edit text only.

Answer (score 8):

It's probably because you are using **3rd party keyboard** instead of the native phone keyboard. 
This often happens with [SwiftKey](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us).

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore them. Its because your OS might have had some new keyboards like Swype, or some other customized keyboards, and these kind of things come popping up. So you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have any element such as button or text view duplicated (copied twice) in the activity xml file that corresponds to the screen where this encounters. I did this unnoticed and had to face the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Add the `android:textIsSelectable="false"` in editText
For example

```
  <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_IONumber"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_shape"
                    android:padding="5dip" />
```