# Best way to get a SpannableString from a SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, performance, spannablestring

I am working in a wiki-like parser that creates spans for a set of markup tokens. It is working, but inside the token iterator I frequently need to convert the partial results on a `SpannableStringBuilder` to a `SpannableString`. This is called pretty frequently, so I'm after the  most efficient solution to do it, and avoid creating extra objects.

At the moment I'm using;

```
SpannableStringBuilder stuff=complex_routine_that_builds_it();
SpannableString result=SpannableString.valueOf(stuff);
```

However this `valueOf` call internally builds a `SpannableString` kind of from scratch, doing a `toString` and a loop to copy assigned `spans`.

As `SpannableStringBuilder` name suggests, I think that maybe there's a quicker way to get the `SpannableString` from the builder. Is it true?

Comment: if you have some spans in your text all you need is android.text.Spanned

Comment: yes I understand it now, the name `SpannableStringBuilder` confused me, I am used to working with `StringBuffer` then getting a `String` at the end, and didn't realized that `SpannableStringBuilder` also implements `Spanned`, `Charsequence`, etc ... The builder comes in handy to me because the parser does a lot of operations on incoming strings to remove markup and create many different spans: URL, colors, sizes, ... Basically I'm rewriting the (terribly) slow `Html.fromHtml`

Comment: great idea, i dont know why but 95% of mates here use fromHtml, even if input is not html : they first build artificial html and then call fromHtml, i cannot find more stupid thing

Comment: yesss and if you look at the Html.java source code you just want to die... it parses the string into a XML SaxParser (!), then uses a 100kb library Tagsoup with zillions of regular expressions that check for well-formedness, XML Schemas and whatnot.... only to support just bold, italic, headers and colors, something I've done with roughly 150 lines and is 10 times faster!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is no need to convert a `SpannableStringBuilder` to a `SpannableString` when you can use it directly, as in a `TextView`:

```
SpannableStringBuilder stuff = complex_routine_that_builds_it();
textView.setText(stuff);
```

As the question already showed, you could make the conversion if you absolutely had to by

```
SpannableStringBuilder stuff = complex_routine_that_builds_it();
SpannableString result = SpannableString.valueOf(stuff);
```

but you should consider why you would even need to make that conversion? Just use the original `SpannableStringBuilder`.

### [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) vs [`SpannableStringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html)

The difference between these two is similar to the difference between `String` and `StringBuilder`. A `String` is immutable but you can change the text in a `StringBuilder`.

Similarly, the text in a `SpannableString` is immutable while the text in a `SpannableStringBuilder` is changeable. It is important to note, though, that this only applies to the text. The spans on both of them (even a `SpannableString`) can be changed.

**Related**

- [Android Spanned, SpannedString, Spannable, SpannableString and CharSequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41935087/3681880)