# getLineStart() including HTML tags in calculation for TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm creating a custom TextView with a somewhat complicated structure. Each sentence needs its own clickHandler, so I'm wrapping each one in a ClickableSpan. Additionally, the text has HTML in, so I also wrap each sentence in HTML.fromHTML() span. The result is something like this:

```
    //IN MY CUSTOM TEXTVIEW
    for (Text text : textList) {
        String words = text.getText(); //Text is my own custom class
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(words);
        ss.setSpan(new ClickableSpan(words) ,0,ss.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ss.setSpan(Html.fromHtml(words),0,ss.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ssb.append(ss);
    }
    setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

However, I have a problem when I try to access text from the textView line by line using `layout.getLineStart(i)`. It seems like it includes the HTML tags in the calculation, even though technically they don't take up any space. How do I specifically leave those tags out of the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't fully understand what Html.fromHtml() returns. It returns a `Spanned`. `SpannableString.setSpan()` takes an `Object` so passing in a `Spanned` didn't cause any errors. However, it didn't have the intended effect of formatting the Html.

Instead, the proper way to do this is:

```
//IN MY CUSTOM TEXTVIEW
for (Text text : textList) {
    String words = text.getText(); //Text is my own custom class

    //note that SpannableString takes CharSequence as parameter
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(words));
    ss.setSpan(new ClickableSpan(words) ,0,ss.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ssb.append(ss);
}
setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Now it works as intended. NOTE: [this SO page was very helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546955/android-spanned-spannedstring-spannable-spannablestring-and-charsequence) in understanding the (extremely confusing) inheritance structure of all the relevant classes