# android search highlight returns previously searched wordstogether with currently searched words

Tags: android

I have code to search a `TextView` and return the searched word with a highlight. The problem is that it keeps the previously searched words highlighted too, instead of starting highlighting anew. Following is my code:

```
            String ett = et.getText().toString();
            String tvt = tvdisplay.getText().toString();
            int ofe = tvt.indexOf(ett,0);

          Spannable WordtoSpan = new                 SpannableString(tvdisplay.getText());
             for (int ofs=0; ofs<tvt.length() && ofe != -1; ofs=ofe+1)
             {

                 ofe = tvt.indexOf(ett, ofs);
                 if (ofe == -1)
                     break;
                 else
                 {

                     WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00),ofe,ofe+ett.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                     tvdisplay.setText(WordtoSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                 }
             }

        }
    });

    }
```

Image of the searched words in the emulator:
[image]

Comment: enter your image properly

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of using `new SpannableString(tvdisplay.getText())` use 
`new SpannableString(tvt)`**

What you want to do is create the new Spannable from the text *String*, and not from the *CharSequence*. But the problem here is that `tvdisplay.getText()`  returns a `CharSequence` - in this case it returns the `SpannableString` you previously set.

If performance is a critical point to your app, you might consider removing the old span with  `removeSpan()` instead of creating a new SpannableString object every time.  For more info on Strings, CharSequences etc. in general check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/17547344/1096567

Comment: Problem solved. That does the trick. How do I make it case insensitive though? If I use caps on a word that is there, it returns no result

Comment: @PamelaSillah create the SpannableString as I wrote above, but perform the search with lowercase versions of the search word and the text (but beware that toLowercase and toUppercase might not work as you expect in some languages).