# Android StringBuilder vs Editable

Tags: android, stringbuilder, android-editable

While trying to comprehend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17547344/3681880), I failed to understand the difference between [`StringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [`Editable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html). This image (minus the hand-drawn red circles) comes from that answer.

[image]

Both of them have methods to `append`, `delete`, `insert`, and `replace` text. I see that `StringBuilder` is an actual class while `Editable` is an interface. But I can get an `Editable` back from a `TextView` with `textView.getEditableText()`, which seems strange if it is an interface. What is the concrete implementation behind the scenes? I also see that `Editable` can have spans while a `StringBuilder` doesn't.

I think I am close to understanding the difference, but I could use a little more explanation. I was surprised that I couldn't find where this question had already been asked, so I am asking it now.

Again, specifically:

- What is the difference between `StringBuilder` and `Editable`?
- When should I use one as opposed to the other?

Comment: Editable can hold markups such html. StringBuilder holds only plain text. What do you mean by *which seems strange if it is an interface* ?

Comment: Is the object that I am getting back from `TextView` actually a `SpannableStringBuilder`? And if so, why do I get an incompatible types error if I write `SpannableStringBuilder myString = textView.getEditableText();`? @Blackbelt

Comment: My question may be evolving into: What is the difference between `SpannableStringBuilder` and `Editable`?

Comment: a `SpannableStringBuilder` is an `Editable`, but an `Editable` is not a `SpannableStringBuilder`. The former is something concrete the latter is an abstraction. You can't assign `getEditableText` to a `SpannableStringBuilder` unless you down cast it. *Is the object that I am getting back from TextView actually a SpannableStringBuilder*, it might be and it might be not.

Comment: @Blackbelt. OK, I think that all makes sense now. Feel free to make your comments an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between StringBuilder and Editable?

`Editable` can hold markups such `html`. `StringBuilder` holds only plain text.

> But I can get an Editable back from a TextView with
>   textView.getEditableText(), which seems strange if it is an interface.
>   What is the concrete implementation behind the scenes?

It is not strange. It returns an `Editable`, the concrete implementation depends on how you set the text.

> is the object that I am getting back from TextView actually a
>   SpannableStringBuilder? And if so, why do I get an incompatible types
>   error if I write SpannableStringBuilder myString =
>   textView.getEditableText();

It might be or it might be not. What you know is that is an Editable. A `SpannableStringBuilder` is an `Editable`, but an `Editable` is not a `SpannableStringBuilder`, that's why you can't assign the return value of `getEditableText` to a `SpannableStringBuilder` unless you down cast it. I