# How android span act on input characters in EditText

Tags: android, html, spannablestring, richedit, spannable

I want to implement a effect that control input characters in edittext whether use span.

For example, in EditText can use

```
getEditableText().setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

make selected characters be **BOLD**.Is There have solutions that when user enable Bold setting, every character input since then will be bold, and once user disable Bold setting, characters input after that will not be bold.

I tried use ***Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE*** as flags in *SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan()*, but I just can control when span's effect start, and can't control end.

Also tried use TextWatcher to listen every character input, and set Span to every character.

```
 @Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter)
{
    setTextSpan(start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
}

private void setTextSpan(int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter)
{
    if (isBold) {
        getEditableText().setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), start, start + lengthAfter, Spanned
                .SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

but when use *Html.toHtml()*, every character be wrapped by `<b></b>`.

Like`<p dir="ltr"><b>1</b><b>1</b><b>1</b><b>1</b><b>1</b><b>1</b></p>`

I read some source code in *SpannableStringBuilder.java*, but do not find any method to change span's effect scope.

Hope someone can give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about TextWatcher that you used, what is the problem?

Comment: @Huo Chhunleng  I'm sorry to reply so late.The problem is, when I use TextWatcher and Input some characters, the display is right, but after convert by *Html.toHtml()*, the result isn't what I want.For example, Input:abdce, after convert I'll obtain '<p dir="ltr"><b>a</b><b>b</b><b>c</b><b>d</b><b>e</b></p>', but I desired result is '<p dir="ltr"><b>abcde</b></p>'

Comment: https://akashkubavat.wordpress.com/tag/remove-underline-from-edittext/

Comment: @Huo Chhunleng In this way ,just can set the selected text bold.The effect I want is that when enable the bold,all characters input after are bold,disable bold , input is normal.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you, have you resolved the problem? Or find other way to achieve?  If so,  high appreciate for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful advices have been found, you can check '[Android EditText: how to apply spans when composing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242210/android-edittext-how-to-apply-spans-when-composing)'.

But, there is also another question:The flag 'SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE' setting font BOLD works well. But, when I switch to set the font NOT BOLD(just return to normal), the text insertted is still BOLD. I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Hi,I have already read the answer you mentioned,that solution can handle some problems, but the situation I encountered is more complicated. I finally thought of two solutions.I will describe these in my answer。

Answer (score 0):

First of all,set `TextWatcher` for EditText. Then there are two solutions.
1. when text changed, if input character, use `removeSpan()`, then use `setSpan()` reset the span's range.
2. Use reflect. `SpannableStringBuilder` has member call `mSpanEnds`, this array record position information for all span in the `SpannableStringBuilder`,use reflect change it's value.
I have a [sample](https://github.com/nebulae-pan/RichEditText/blob/master/rich_edittext/src/main/java/com/pxh/adapter/SpanAdapter.java) for solution 2,this sample may have some bugs,but it works well in apply spans.