# How can i bold and color of paticular textview item?

Tags: android, textview

I want to bold and color of single textview item.ex- 23870.This is a value of textview and i want to bold of 8 and 7 chracter.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`Spannable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android) for your textview

and also check [this](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
Spannable str = 23870; 
str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 2, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

check this