# How to change text color based on the availability in android?

Tags: android, json, url

I am parsing a JSON data from a URL.
i am using [this example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/) to parse the data
i successfully parsed the data, now i want a little bit thing that if the product available i want to keep this in green color but if the product available i want the keep that name in some other color.

my Data for the availability is.

this is my json data for available

```
       {
          "id":"1234",
          "price": "311.95",
          "seller": "Shopclues.com",
          "availability": "Available",
          "currency": "USD"
        }
```

this is for not avaliable

```
        {
          "id":"4321"
          "price": "290.05",
          "seller": "Tradus.com",
          "availability": "Not Available",
          "currency": "USD"
        }
```

So i want the data like if product is avaliable
i want that  "id":"1234" should be in green colour other wise it should some other color like black or gray or red.

i tried with normal data but this i am getting forma  URL so give me any suggestion for dynamic JSON data which is getting from a url.

Comment: then pls post your adapter code.So we can help you

Comment: how you are parsing it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(String);
if (jObj.getString("availability").equalsIgnoreCase("Not Available")) {
     textView1.setTextColor(Color.RED)
} else {
      textView1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(String);
if (jObj.getString("availability").equalsIgnoreCase("Not Available")) {
       //textcolor = red
} else {
       //textcolor = green
}
```

Comment: Thanks you Kalyaganov Alexey sir , but where did i need to diclare the color wether in xml or class file and one more doubht sir if i keep this condition did only ID will change to that color or entire data. i am trying but i seen that no changes made.. please let me know sir..

Comment: You can put the color in xml file and can refer from there also you can set the color code directly in the `setColor` method also in hexadecimal format. @user3124880

Comment: sir is there any example please let me know i tried with offline application but i want with online applications..please help sir

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change part of a string, then use `Spannable` in android. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android) for an example. Otherwise `TextView` has a setTextColor method which takes an int. This int is NOT the resource id. It should be used as follows `textView1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor))` or `textView1.setTextColor(Color.RED)`

Comment: Its ok Ali sir but i want to remove availability from that string because i dont have place to display that so i want to keep that if this id is available i want to keep that id in green if not there i need to show some other color i am parsing the data from a url..

Comment: It sounds like you are displaying the above JSON. In that cause you have 2 options, either read the JSON into a JSONObject and remove the availability key from the JSONObject and print it out again. Or just use `String.indexOf()` to check if the `"availability:"Available"` exists and use `String.replace()` to remove it. Since you use indexOf to check if it existed, you can use that to set the color as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out..

```
     JSONObject object= new JSONObject(String);
     if (object.getString("availability").equalsIgnoreCase("Available")) {
           textView1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
     } else {
           textView1.setTextColor(Color.RED)
     }
```