# Android - Change Background Color of a part of String in EditText(Highlighting Text)

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I'm making an app in which I there is an `EditText` and a `ToggleButton`. I want to create a highlighter mechanism with the help of these. For example, when the state of the `ToggleButton` is **ON**, the text that'll be entered in the `EditText` will have Green background as if it is being highlighted. Again, when the `ToggleButton` state will be changed to **OFF**, the text in the `EditText` will also stop getting highlighted immediately.

Please Help Me.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background color of part of the text using SpannableString as described here: [Set color of TextView span in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)

Another way of doing the same thing is to load the text from HTML with the  tag set to the background color you want.

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of text use

```
textElement.setTextColor(0xFF00FF00); //this is green colour
```

To change the colour of edit text use

```
textElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

For more information Check this [link](http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-1-3-how-to-change-a-color-of-text-and-background-in-textview/).

Answer (score 0):

Simply you set `onCheckedChangeListener` on your `ToggleButton` to change the background of your `EditText`. Your code will be something like this :

```
toggleButtonHighLight.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
        if (checked) {
            //highlight the EditText by setting its background to green
            editText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
        } else {
            //delete the highlight when the toggleButton is OFF
            editText.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately, the app crashes with a java.lang.NullPointerException !!!

Comment: it's because you are not getting the edittext from your xml, try `EditText editText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);`.
if you want more help , you should share more code and the more logs about the stack trace of the exceptions you got . i can't figure out the solution magically like that without having any idea about what's going on in your code