# Android: Using Spannable class when text added dynamically?

Tags: android, sqlite, textview, spannablestring

I am trying to change the color of certain text in my TextView, and I am aware of using `Spannable class` from [this Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)

My issue is that my text is added dynamically as a return value from an SQLite database query.

Can I still use Spannable, if so then how?

**Code section where text set in TextView:**

```
case R.id.btnAvgAttSearch:

            final String entry = avgEntered.getText().toString();
            // convert from string value to int
            int avgValToSearch = Integer.parseInt(entry); //

            // /setting results equal to return val of search
            results = db.getSpecificAverageAtt(avgValToSearch);


            tvResults.setText(listToString(results));

             }

            break;
```

**Example output in TextView, note that circled areas are the lines I wish to be in red:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

**ListToString Method:**

```
public static String listToString(List<?> list) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result += "" + list.get(i) + "\n\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change ListToSTring to return a `Spannable`, for instance:

```
public static Spannable listToString(List<?> list) {
    SpannableStringBuilder result = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        result.append(list.get(i)).append("\n\n");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you can programmatically add spans to the result.

```
Spannable text = listToString(results);
text.setSpan( /*.. span goes here */ );
tvResults.setText(text);
```