# change backgroundcolor of text in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext box and I would like to change the background color of text in edittext and not edittext background color.Basically there will be 2 background color in the end both edittext background color and textbackground color.How can add textbackground color to edittext?

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
```

Comment: android:textColor="#000" android:background="#ff0", i am confused

Comment: that´s not possible by the usual way. I think You have to design a xml layout (for example a  shape) for that and set it as background of edit text...

Comment: <FrameLayout android:background = "#000""><EditText/></FrameLayout>

Comment: How can I do that ? I thought we can handle both background color the same way but I couldn't.Can you share any link or article for the same?

Comment: @PiotrGolinski Please can you elaborate .I tried your code but was not working.

Comment: @jason, You want to change the text background color?

Comment: may this helps you:
use this for edit text.[click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F00">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#0F0"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

    <!---------------just add these two lines---------------------------->
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"`      
    android:background="@android:color/blue"`

/>
```