# TextColors in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

This may be a ridiculous question ever, but still I want to reduce my effort of creating a lot of text views.

I have text view that contains **Name:Value** format [Suppose Name:Android] In this case all the attributes for the text view will be same except the color and also the texts are side by side.

In real implementation I have to create two text views, and suppose if I have around 10-15 such pairs, the number of text views will be 20-30 respectively.

**So how can I set different color for name and value independently??**

Comment: With a [`ForegroundColorSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html). You can probably find examples of how to use it by searching here at StackOverflow.

Comment: sound new to me..let me try and come back..Gracious coz thanks not allowed in stack(Lolzz)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like

```
String str = "<font color=#900000 >Name:</font> <font color=#0000FF>Android</font>";
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text to use html  tags to set colors inside the text

```
String formattedText = "<font color=\"#ff0000\">red</font> <font color=\"#00ff00\">green</font>";
Spanned result = Html.fromHtml(formattedText);
view.setText(result);
```

Or, use spannable like in [Set color of TextView span in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)