# How to set text color of each word in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView with a custom adapter. What I want is when I type a text in the searchbox, I want to set text color only to the word in suggestion that contains the text and not the whole suggestion. How do I do it. Below is my custom adapter.

```
public class SearchAutoComplectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TagBo> {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflate;
    private VenueFilter filter;

    public SearchAutoComplectAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        this.context = context;
        inflate = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflate.inflate(R.layout.search_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView venueName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_venue_name);
        venueName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.cyan));
        TextView venueAddress = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.search_item_venue_address);

        TagBo recordBo=getItem(position);

        // TODO add shared With Me check
        if(recordBo.getTagTypeId() == 3){
            venueName.setText(recordBo.getName());
            venueAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            venueName.setText(recordBo.getName());
            venueAddress.setText(recordBo.getSuggestText());
            venueAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new VenueFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }


    private class VenueFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();

            if(constraint!=null ){

                List<TagBo> matchingTags = TagDao.getMatchingTags(constraint.toString());
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                for (TagBo tag : matchingTags) {
                    text.append(tag.getSuggestText() + "\n");
                }
                result.values = matchingTags;
                result.count = matchingTags.size();
            }else{
                result.count = 0;
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            // we clear the adapter and then pupulate it with the new results
            clear();
            if (results.count > 0) {
                for (TagBo o : (ArrayList<TagBo>) results.values) {
                    add(o);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: using spannable string ref this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android

Comment: @AdityaSawant, if any of the answers help you, don't forget to accept and /or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u need to use SpannableString as param of setText();
u can use mSpannableString.setSpan(new Forgbackground(color)) to custom evety word in String