# changing font color of part of textview that uses a custom typeface

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I have implemented a custom typeface throughout my app using the `uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0` library.

I now need to change the color of part of a textview. I have tried to use

`String username = "<font color='#FC195A'>" + post.getUsername() + "</font>";`

but the font color remains the same.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: use [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spannable String to get your thing done.

Just follow below link :

[Set color of TextView span in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)

To provide color to the username, first get the length of it and do as below :

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(username);        
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, username.length();, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
usernameTextView.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

Comment: This assumes that the length of the text is definite. In my case, the length of the text varies.

Comment: Then, You can store particular text into a String Variable and getting value and length of that, assign color for it.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring the typeface as shown below

```
// Create the Typeface you want to apply to certain text
CalligraphyTypefaceSpan typefaceSpan = new CalligraphyTypefaceSpan(TypefaceUtils.load(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"));
// Apply typeface to the Spannable 0 - 6 "Hello!" This can of course by dynamic.
sBuilder.setSpan(typefaceSpan, 0, 6, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
setText(sBuilder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

add the set text color option

```
setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```