# How to add interactive text in android how to bold and italic text

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I want to make text like this image can anyone tell me how to make this type of text and how to make bold and italic it and how to give specs in between the two lines.

[image]

Comment: Use Html.fromHtml(String) : example <b>we the people of india</b>, you need to put html tags     Html.fromHtml(String, int) // for 24 api and more

Comment: Html.fromHtml is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with android `Spannable`
Refer this doc https://blog.stylingandroid.com/introduction-to-spans/

Answer (score 0):

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3282940/6333971)

[And Read this Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html)

Also check [this](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html) one its show different style on text view using **Spannable**