# How to design textview dynamic like this?

Tags: android, textview

I need to design two textview like this:

[image: Desired design]

I am trying to do the same by two TextViews, but as the next TextView is at the end of the first one, it appears beside the first one. I need only the first line to be beside the first one and the rest below that.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-androidf

Comment: Check this - https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: There is no such UITextView component on Android. You likely are referring to a TextView.

Answer (score 1):

Use html string with different color as below.

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='your color code'>simple</font>.This is <font color='your color code'>simple</font>";

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one `TextView` instead two, and then use `'SpannableString'` to customized front's style.
like this:

```
new SpannableString("string").setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.MAGENTA), 12, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```