# Android. Has universal method for string text color for Android 4.0+?

Tags: android

> Suppose I want to color part of text (words **do you**) in the
>   sentence.
>
> So I use this:
>
> ```
> <string name="congratulations">Hello, how <font color="#00FFFF">do you</font> do</string>
> ```
>
> But this not work on Android 4.0.
>
> So for fix this I use next:
>
> ```
> <string name="congratulations">Hello, how <font fgcolor="#FF00FFFF">do you</font> do</string>
> ```
>
> But this not work for Android 4.3.
>
> Has universal approach that will be work for all Android 4.0+ version
>   AND for different languages?

I found that this not work on device:  OS Version: 4.4.2
 Device: HTC Desire 610. So at finally I use this solution:

```
<string name="expand"><![CDATA[<font color=#00FFFF>+</font> My contacts]]></string>.
```

Of course you need in java code use this:

```
Html.fromHtml(source);
```

So now it's work for all Adnroid 4.0+ and for all languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done something quite similar with `SpannableString`. look at this example:

```
String a = getString(R.string.string1);
String b = getString(R.string.string2);

Spanned color1 = setSpanColor(a,Color.CYAN);
Spanned color2 = setSpanColor(b,Color.RED);
Spanned mixedColor = TextUtils.concat(color1, " ", color2);
// Now use `mixedColor`
```

**setSpanColor**

```
public Spanned setSpanColor(String string, int color){
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(string);
    ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, string.length(), 0);
    //ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, string.length(), 0);
    builder.append(ss);
    return ss;
}
```

**Update**

Another way is to do it with `Html` format wich supports all `API` levels as well:

```
Spanned text;
String yourText = getResources().getString(R.string.congratulations);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    // For API 24(nougat)+
    text =(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFEB3B'><b>"+yourText+"</b></font>",Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
     // pre API 24
     text =(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFEB3B'><b>"+yourText+"</b></font>"));
}
// Now use `text`
```

Answer (score 0):

Along @S.R answer you may Try dynamically. got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);

Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers");        

wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TV.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

Comment: what about multi languages? Scope from 15 to 30 is correct for English, but not correct fro Spain (from 16 to 37).