# How to set dynamically color for TextView in Android

Tags: java, android, textview

In my application I want show some text into `TextView`, and I get this **text** from **server**.
I should use just one `textView` in XML layout, and I should set **color** for this **Texts**. 
**My XML :**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowExplore_userName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size3"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding8"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rowExplore_imageCard"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="Adam"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font14" />
```

**JSON :**

```
  "name": "Adam Sandel",
  "info": "liked",
  "movieName": "SpiderMan",
```

**Java code :**

```
rowExplore_userName.setText(response.getName() + response.getInfo() + response.getMovieName() );
```

I want set color dynamically such as below image : 
[image]

How can I it? Please help me

Comment: I think this would help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>First Color</font> <font color=#ffcc00>Second Color</font>";
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach to this is to create a string resource with appropriate HTML tags:

```
<string name="html_string" formatted="false">
    <![CDATA[
       <font color="yellow">%s</font> %s <font color="yellow">%s</font>
    ]]>
</string>
```

And then get that string with resources:

```
String htmlString = getString(R.strings.html_string, response.getName(), response.getInfo(), response.getMovieName());
rowExplore_userName.setText(htmlString);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this code:

```
String colorStr="#FFFFFF" //put your hex color 
int color =  Color.parseColor(colorStr);
editText.setTextColor(color);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SpannableString` if you want to avoid using HTML tags

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString("Your text is here");        
wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), indexStart, indexEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(wordToSpan);
```

and it is more flexible since you can make more changes to your text (text size, bold/italic, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I would have another approach just create one method

```
 public String getColoredString(String pname) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(pname);
    wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, pname.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return wordToSpan.toString();
}
```

and use above method

```
rowExplore_userName.setText(getColoredString(response.getName())+getColoredString(response.getInfo())+getColoredString(response.getMovieName()));
```

this should work.