# How to give specific colors to words using Spannable?

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` and contains the below text

```
The -[[community]]- is here to help you with -[[specific]]- coding, -[[algorithm]]-, or -[[language]]- problems.
```

I want anything inside `-[[]]-` take red color, How can I do that using `Spannable`?

And I don't want to show `-[[` and `]]-` in `TextView`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set color of TextView span in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)

Comment: @Noah No that is different.

Comment: It's the same. Read the whole post.

Comment: if the square brackets are necessary, you should the index of the String in the bracket and apply the colours using Spannables. Then you remove the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SpannableStringBuilder` and append parts of `String` colorizing them when necessary. For example,

```java
static CharSequence colorize(
        String input, String open, String close, @ColorInt int color
) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    int openLen = open.length(), closeLen = close.length();
    int openAt, contentAt, closeAt, last = 0;
    while ((openAt = input.indexOf(open, last)) >= 0 &&
            (closeAt = input
                    .indexOf(close, contentAt = openAt + openLen)) >= 0) {
        int start = builder.append(input, last, openAt).length();
        int len = builder.append(input, contentAt, closeAt).length();
        builder.setSpan(
                new ForegroundColorSpan(color),
                start, len, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        );
        last = closeAt + closeLen;
    }
    return builder.append(input, last, input.length());
}
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (7 ... 16) ends beyond length 13`

Comment: @Ahmed, my bad, I've updated the answer.

Comment: It's working, I'll understand the code now. Thanks

Comment: Check my update in your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Ahmed, nice catch! I've updated the code on my own because `SpannableStringBuilder.toString()` would waste much memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CodeView library to highlight many patterns with different colors, in your case for example the code will be like this

```java
CodeView codeView = findViewById(R.id.codeview);
codeView.addSyntaxPattern(Pattern.compile("-\\[\\[[a-zA-Z]+]]-"), Color.GREEN);
codeView.setTextHighlighted(text);
```

And the result will be:

[image]

If the highlighted keywords are unique you can highlight them without using -[[]]- just create a pattern that can cover them

You can change the color, add or remove patterns in the runtime

CodeView Repository URL: https://github.com/amrdeveloper/codeview

Comment: This is just another option and developers choose what they want be depending on his case,

Comment: well, am not against using the library, but using a library for this small task is just not good.

Comment: You are right Noah if is just one task, but this option is if you want to implement it many time or with multiple patterns and colors and if you want to change the highlight color depend on the current theme

Comment: I don't like to use any external library for small things, Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The value in the variable who named `open` must be different from the value in the variable who named `close`, If the value was the same will cause a problem. You need to change variables values only to work well.

```
String open = "-[[";
String close = "]]-";
int color = Color.RED;
String s1 = "The -[[community]]- is here to help you with -[[specific]]- coding, -[[algorithm]]-, or -[[language]]- problems.";
SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(s1);
while (spannableStringBuilder.toString().contains(open) && spannableStringBuilder.toString().contains(close)) {
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), spannableStringBuilder.toString().indexOf(open) + open.length(), spannableStringBuilder.toString().indexOf(close) + close.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableStringBuilder.replace(spannableStringBuilder.toString().indexOf(open), spannableStringBuilder.toString().indexOf(open) + open.length(), "").replace(spannableStringBuilder.toString().indexOf(close), spannableStringBuilder.toString().indexOf(close) + close.length(), "");
}
yourTextView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
```

Comment: Format your code please