# Best approach to set some long text on a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have to display some long text on a TextView, i tried to put it on `strings.xml` variable but had that problem `Apostrophe not preceded by \`. I used Java code to set the TextView but all the text must be on one line, and i want that the compiler detects return to line.

My question what is the best approach to make that ?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mTextSample.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));` Where you can show anything in your TextView using [Html.fromHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29).

Example (Some uses):

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

.

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

And some uses :

[Android Html.fromHtml takes too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153154/android-html-fromhtml-takes-too-long)

[Display HTML Formatted String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478503/display-html-formatted-string)

Happy coding :)

Comment: Wow, i'm loving that, you can adjust some properties "in the air", bold, italic,size, font... Awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should add it to the strings.xml and add escape characters for all 'sensitive' characters you may use, such as apostrophe. For example

```
<string name="test">It\'s me</string>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you are having long text to display in text view then should try to set pro grammatically like
String text = "Your Text goes here, what ever you want to display";

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

tv.setText(text);

Don't forget to put your text view under a scroll view in your layout for better User Expierence.

Comment: And for return to lines? How can i do it ?